# Exporting from EXCEL to Access with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have this code i found online to export data from Excel to Access and it works fine to an extent but i am having issues with trying to export a range of cells. I can export one cell but it doesn't see to like when try to export a range. Instead i am trying to use a loop instead to export the range but still can't get it to work.

I get the Next without for Error

I have tried this method with no luck either 'rs!Column1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:O170")

Code below:

```
Sub AdddNewDatatoAccDb()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset

Dim i As Integer

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

 With cn
.ConnectionString = con1
.Open "T:\Folder1\VBA Test.accdb"
End With


Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "VBAtest", cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

For i = 0 To 170

With rs

.AddNew

rs!Column1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 0).Value

rs!Column2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 1).Value

Next i
End With

Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

Exit Sub
End Sub
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile as posted. You have your with block started inside a loop but ended outside the loop, which is invalid. You are missing an `.Update` call after the `.AddNew`. If we pass the field and the value to the `.AddNew` command then we don't need the `.Update`

I recommend using the `With` block to control the scope of your objects instead of setting them to nothing. Always closing before the `End With`. Notice I use an error handler to ensure that the close is always called. This should allow graceful destruction of your DB objects.

Here is an example that I can't test. You will likely need to do some tweaks to make it fit your environment:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AdddNewDatatoAccDb(ByVal con1 As String)

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    With ADODB.Connection
        .ConnectionString = con1
        .Open "T:\Folder1\VBA Test.accdb"
        With ADODB.Recordset
            .Open "VBAtest", .ConnectionString, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 0 To 170
                .AddNew "Column1", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 0).Value
                .AddNew "Column2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 2, 1).Value
            Next i

errHandler:            
            .Close
        End With
        
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have MSAccess.exe (i.e., the Office software) installed, consider directly querying the Excel workbook from Access using SQL. No loops required.

Below include two different ways both aliasing to `t` and assumes headers are in specified range. You can save them as stored queries in Access for later use and even incorporate in append queries.

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx][Sheet1$O2:O170] AS t;
```

```sql
SELECT t.*
FROM [Sheet1$O2:O170] As t IN 'C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes];
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AdddNewDatatoAccDb()

    Const DB = "T:\Folder1\VBA Test.accdb"
    Const TABLE = "VBAtest"

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ar, i As Integer
    Dim fields(1), values(1)
    
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & DB
        .Open
    End With

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open TABLE, cn, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic, adCmdTable

    ar = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("O2:P172").Value
    fields(0) = "Column1"
    fields(1) = "Column2"

    For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
        values(0) = ar(i, 1)
        values(1) = ar(i, 2)
        rs.AddNew fields, values
    Next i
   
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    MsgBox i - 1 & " records inserted", vbInformation
End Sub
```